# Is Python's logger able to rotate log files?

Tags: python, logging

Is there a way to use the logging module shipped within python to rotate the log file? Like that in logrotate?

I used logrotate but it gave some bizzare result.

Comment: linux ubuntu version 2.6.32

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose [this](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-file-rotation) could help you.

Yes, you can similary to `logrotate` in Linux rotate logfiles in Python too. Following is a small example from the link above:

```
import glob
import logging
import logging.handlers

LOG_FILENAME = 'logging_rotatingfile_example.out'

# Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Add the log message handler to the logger
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
              LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=20, backupCount=5)

my_logger.addHandler(handler)

# Log some messages
for i in range(20):
    my_logger.debug('i = %d' % i)

# See what files are created
logfiles = glob.glob('%s*' % LOG_FILENAME)

for filename in logfiles:
    print(filename)
```

The output of the script is:

```
logging_rotatingfile_example.out
logging_rotatingfile_example.out.1
logging_rotatingfile_example.out.2
logging_rotatingfile_example.out.3
logging_rotatingfile_example.out.4
logging_rotatingfile_example.out.5
```

The most current file is always `logging_rotatingfile_example.out` an each time it reaches the size limit it is renamed with the suffix `.i`. Each of the existing backup files is renamed to increment the suffix (.1 becomes .2, etc.).

This is just a show example. In real life scenario you should set the `maxBytes` to an appropriate value.

Source: [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html) (the listed above article, in case the link gets broken)

Comment: A complete explanation from the source is added.