# log setup with formatting and logrotate

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, logrotate

Below program I am trying to setup the logs with my required formatting using `basicConfig` and use `RotatingFileHandler` to rotate the logs.

But getting the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 77, in emit  
    self.doRollover()  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 142, in doRollover  
    os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)  
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process  
Logged from file log_rotate.py, line 53
```

Could not figure out where is the problem, new to python.
Can someone please point me in right direction.

```
import os
import logging
import time
import string
from ctypes import windll
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

LOG_FILE = 'C:\\temp\\debug.log'

def get_drives():
    drives = []
    bitmask = windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
    for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
        if bitmask & 1:
            drives.append(letter)
        bitmask >>= 1

    return drives

def create_temp_dir():

    drives = []
    drives = get_drives()
    temp_dir = drives[0]+':\\temp\\'
    if not os.path.exists(temp_dir):
        print ( " creating temp for logs and etc ", temp_dir )
        os.makedirs(temp_dir)
    return temp_dir

def make_log_setup():
    global LOG_FILE
    temp_dir = create_temp_dir()
    log_file = temp_dir+'debug.log'
    date_strftime_format = "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S"
    message_format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(filename = log_file, format = message_format, datefmt = date_strftime_format,level=logging.DEBUG)

def create_rotating_log(path):
    """
    Creates a rotating log
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    
    # add a rotating handler
    handler = RotatingFileHandler(path, maxBytes=20,
                                  backupCount=5)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    
    for i in range(6):
        logger.info("This is test log line %s" % i)
        time.sleep(1.5)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #log_file = "test.log"
    make_log_setup()
    create_rotating_log(LOG_FILE)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the filename and ensuring no other process(es) are using the file(s)?

Comment: @ELinda , I don't get , why to change the file name, `backupCount=5` is used to create files appended by 1 to 5 right? or my understanding is wrong?

Comment: After commenting `for` loop the error is gone, but the statements like `logging.info("This is test log line")` after `create_rotating_log(LOG_FILE)` are not generating the log files (rotated files)

Comment: After spending some time and going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459850/permissionerror-when-using-python-3-3-4-and-rotatingfilehandler) removing `filename = log_file,` from `logging.basicConfig` removed the error, but now the problem is logs are coming only on console , not coming to log_file, anyone kindly help me to solve the problem

Comment: See my answer here ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872435/is-pythons-logger-able-to-rotate-log-files/70941967#70941967